# How to create a custom resultAdapter for select2 jquery component

Tags: javascript, jquery, adapter, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using version 4.0.2 of the Select2 jquery component:
https://select2.github.io/

There is an issue where it continues to show selected items in the drop down, and the behavior we want is to not show selected items in the drop down.

I found the following issue in their repo where some people have show workarounds they have used.  You can use CSS to hide the selected items, but the issue is that if you use the arrow keys to navigate up and down the list in the drop down, it still counts the hidden items, and the selection in the drop down will disappear as you move over the hidden items as pointed out here:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1538#issuecomment-125876946

Other suggestions use a custom resultAdapter to solve the problem.  I have tried all the suggested approaches but none of them work for me.  They all throw errors like `decorated` doesn't exist etc...
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1538#issuecomment-226491682
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1538#issuecomment-229608717

One guy has offered a pure jquery solution, which is what I am after, but it doesn't work either complaining that the `render` function doesn't exist:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1538#issuecomment-234274624

What I really need to know is what am I spost to return.  I have tried returning an object with a render function, but then it complains that other jquery link functions are missing, like `postion`, `bind` and `on`.
What exactly am I spost to return.

Currently I have the following:

```
function getNotSelectedResults(self, options, dataAdapter) {
    var aSelectedItems = $('li.select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"]'),
        aAllItems = $('#ID_OF_Select2 option');
    return {
        render: function () {
            return $.map(aAllItems, function (eItem, i) {
                return aSelectedItems.find(':contains("Certified Bobcat Operator")').length > 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Which I am wiring up like this:

```
$element.select2({
    resultsAdapter: getNotSelectedResults
});
```

But it complains that `position` is not a function.

I have searched hi and low and can't find any solid example of how to build a custom ResultsAdapter that works.

Can anyone point me to a solid example of building a custom ResultsAdapter for the select2 jquery component?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This might be helpful for anyone searching for how to make an adapter: https://bojanv91.github.io/posts/2017/10/extending-select2-with-adapters-and-decorators